# Set Modbus Register via CEP operation

Tags: modbus, complex-event-processing, cumulocity

I wanted to set the holding registers of a Modbus Relay to toggle devices.

I know the parameters, registers and values which have to be set, but the CEP operation is not working.

I have tried different methods of indicating the objects.

```
  select
    "PENDING" as status,
    9716636 as deviceId,
    {
      "deviceName", "Modbus Relais",
      "description", "Relais-Status auf CLOSE setzen",
      "c8y_setRegister.input", "false",  
      "c8y_setRegister.address", "1", 
      "c8y_setRegister.startBit", "0",
      "c8y_setRegister.noBits", "16",
      "c8y_setRegister.ipAddress", "",
      "c8y_setRegister.value", "256",
      "c8y_setRegister.register", "2"

    } as fragments
  from MeasurementCreated e
  where getNumber(e, "c8y_Temperaturecy.T.value") > 2
```

but the register is not being set

Answer (score 0):

solved by myself: c8y_SetRegister --> s needs to be uppercase